# User Defined Package Does Not Exist - But it Does

Tags: java, classpath

Working with a legacy Java application in which the user defined packages are no longer visible when compiling classes that are importing.

Can compile the packages (ie: package test.package;) and the .class files are properly located.

But when compiling MyServlet.class - getting "package test.package does not exist" error.

The "import test.package;" are declared in MyServlet.class.

As mentioned, this is a legacy application (java 1.6) and these classes and packages have not changed location or how they are compiled for years.

The user defined packages are compiled fine and are in the proper directory structure, so they exist. But, any servlets importing these packages can't be compiled.

It appears that perhaps the Tomcat, JAVA and/or JDK/JRE have been attempted to be upgraded, thus the CLASSPATH may have been changed. Tried to tweak the CLASSPATH and Environmental Variables. But, still no luck.

Any insight or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Best,
Matthew

We've tried to tweak the CLASSPATH and create new Package locations. But same "package test1.package does not exist".

Comment: You're lacking like a zillion details here.

Comment: Understood Kayaman and appreciate the response. Since the file structure and java code has not changed in years, didn't want to overload with details. Was hoping that someone has had a similar experience. But certainly, I can provide any details that you think may be helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We restored the machine to a previous version which removed the JRE updates that were creating our issues. Case closed.